# how to map an array with uppercase function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, uppercase

I'm interested if there is any function like array_map or array_walk from php.

Don't need an for that travels all the array. I can do that for myself.

```
var array = ['dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mer', 'gio', 'ven', 'sab'];
// i would like something like this if exists - function(array, 'upperCase');
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) in order to apply [String.toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) (or [String.toLocaleUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase), if appropriate) to your array items:

```
var upperCasedArray = $.map(array, String.toUpperCase);
```

Note that `$.map()` builds a new array. If you want to modify your existing array in-place, you can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) with an anonymous function:

```
$.each(array, function(index, item) {
    array[index] = item.toUpperCase();
});
```

**Update:** As afanasy rightfully points out in the comments below, mapping `String.toUpperCase` directly will only work in Gecko-based browsers.

To support the other browsers, you can provide your own function:

```
var upperCasedArray = $.map(array, function(item, index) {
    return item.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: @afanasy, true, I'm probably using Firefox too much. I updated my answer with a portable mapping solution.

Answer (score 11):

Check out [JavaScript Array.map](http://www.javascripture.com/Array#map) for info on the official
JavaScript map function. You can play around with the sample there to
see how the function works.  Try copying this into the example box:

```
var array = ['dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mer', 'gio', 'ven', 'sab'];
var uppers = array.map(function(x) { return x.toUpperCase(); });
console.log(uppers);
```

And it will print:

```
DOM,LUN,MAR,MER,GIO,VEN,SAB
```

Answer (score 8):

This may be an overkill but you can also do

```
var upperCaseArray = array.map(String.prototype.toUpperCase.call.bind(String.prototype.toUpperCase));
```

Comment: @nkron's answer is similar to this, but less verbose.

Comment: That code is a bit confusing because the `String.prototype.toUpperCase.call` part of the code is just accessing the [Function's call](http://www.javascripture.com/Function#call) method. That method is the same for all Functions so you can stick any Function to the left of .call without changing the behavior.  I'd suggest changing it to `Function.prototype.call...` to be explicit that you are using Function's call, not a special feature of the toUpperCase function.

Comment: The clearer example is: `['a','b','c'].map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.toUpperCase))`

Answer (score 5):

You can implement a function for it:

```
Array.prototype.myUcase=function()
{
  for (i=0;i<this.length;i++)
    {
    this[i]=this[i].toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
var fruits=["Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango"];
fruits.myUcase();
```

**RESULT**

```
BANANA,ORANGE,APPLE,MANGO
```

Reference [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_array.asp)

Answer (score 5):

And here is the one-liner without creating a loop or a function that is ES3 compatible
It's alos faster since you only call toUpperCase once

```
// watch out for strings with comma (eg: ["hi, max"]) then use custom join/split()
// or just use something safer such as Array.map()
var uppercaseArray = array.toString().toUpperCase().split(",");
var uppercaseArray = array.join(0).toUpperCase().split(0);
var uppercaseArray = (array+"").toUpperCase().split(",");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could consider using the [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library which provides standard functional operations.

Then the code would be as simple as:

```
_.map(array, function (x) { return x.toUpperCase(); });
```

Comment: also:  `_.map(array, _.upperCase)`

Answer (score 3):

`map()` is somehow similar to `array_walk`

http://jqapi.com/#p=map

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has a map() method. A good reference is at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm

Answer (score 1):

I understand it is a little late to the party, but I wanted to add this here as another Delegation way of doing it.

```
var array = ['dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mer', 'gio', 'ven', 'sab'];

"".toUpperCase.apply(array).split(',')
```

Comment: wow.... care to explain how it's working. how/why is apply converting array to string

Comment: sure. Since I wanted to 'toUpperCase', I needed to be able to delegate to it, or borrow that functionality. Since, I needed an array to do it, I had to somehow pass the "context" IN to the "toUpperCase". apply (since we are using an array), allows this. because I didn't pass a second arg, the first arg "array", is the context. So basically, it spreads it out for me... then I split it to turn it back into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a previous for loop answer, this one uses some of the more basic features of javascript:

```
function looptoUpper(arr){
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        newArr.push(arr[i].toUpperCase());
    }
    return newArr;
}
looptoUpper(['dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mer', 'gio', 'ven', 'sab']);
```