# Convert array into upper case

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that I want to change to upper case but I can´t make it work. Please help me.

```
var array2 = ["melon","banana","apple","orange","lemon"];

array2.toUpperCase()
```

I have also tried the below but it doesn´t work neither.

```
array2.map(toUpperCase);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939803/how-to-map-an-array-with-uppercase-function-in-javascript

Comment: Your attempts didn't work because a) arrays don't have a `toUpperCase` method and b) there is no `toUpperCase` function.

Comment: this works: array2.map(fruit => fruit.toUpperCase())

Answer (score 81, accepted):

you should use handler function in map:

```
var array2 = ["melon","banana","apple","orange","lemon"];
array2 = array2.map(function(x){ return x.toUpperCase(); })
```

[for more information about map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

edit: yes you can do

```
toUpper = function(x){ 
  return x.toUpperCase();
};
array2 = array2.map(toUpper);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When using .map( function(x)... Should I always define a function then? Or can I use already existing? If yes, how do I write it then? Thanks

Comment: @BjornRunow: you just have to pass a function. `.map` doesn't care where it comes from.

Comment: @BjornRunow check post

Comment: new_array = array2.map(function(x){ return x.toUpperCase() });   (map returns a new array, but the example suggests it changes the original array)

Comment: the answer is wrong :( see Marcel's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29719380/1786393

Answer (score 8):

`toUpperCase()` do not change the value.
Try

```
array2 = array2.map(function (e) { 
    return e.toUpperCase()
});
```

Comment: Marcel is right. His answer is the correct one. You need to be able to store the map function in another variable, and not try to mutate the original array as @eddyparkinson points out as well.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this :

```
var a = ['this','is','test'];

a.map(f=>{ return f.toUpperCase(); });
```

Comment: You're using ES6. `return` + braces is unnecessary...

Answer (score 3):

Map is the way I'd recommend, but here's an alternate that may possibly help someone wishing to understand apply used on an objects prototype.

This is an example of an array borrowing the String objects .toUpperCase() method with .apply() and using it on said array.  The array is coerced to a string using .apply() and then back to an uppercased array using the .split() method.

```
arr = ["fulu", "nulu", "hulu"];
var arrToUp = String.prototype.toUpperCase.apply(arr).split(",");

console.log(arrToUp)
//["FULU", "NULU", "HULU"]
```

Comment: OK, but you better don't have any coma in your data.

Comment: fail in case, `arr = ["fu,lu", "nulu", "hulu"]`

Answer (score 2):

Try looping through each element and making it upper case.

```
for(var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
    array2[i] = array2[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: - for using int in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can add the method toUpperCase() to Array.prototype:

```
Array.prototype.toUpperCase = function(){
   return this.map( (el) => (typeof el === "string") ? el.toUpperCase() : el)}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the simplest solution without having to loop through the array.

```
const yourArray = ["apple","banana"];
const upperCasedArray = String(yourArray).toUpperCase().split(",");
//OR
const upperCasedArray = yourArray.toString().toUpperCase().split(",");
```

What's happening is first we convert the array into a string then use the toUpperCase() method of string to make that string all uppercased then split it by using "," so we get a new array which is uppercased.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not really support a `toUpperCase()` function for arrays, as far as I know. You have to create a `for` or `foreach` loop to loop through the array and call `.toUpperCase()` on each element in the array.

You could also create a little function like so: [other question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939803/how-to-map-an-array-with-uppercase-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["hamed","hassan","hema","zeiad","saad","omar","ali","sayed","ahmed"];
var str = String(arr).toUpperCase().split(",");
```

Comment: fail in case, `arr = ["ha,med","hassan","hema","zeiad","saad","omar","ali","sayed","ahmed"]`

Answer (score 0):

#### Underscore.js

If you're using Underscore.js and cannot use ES6 niceties then it's something like this:

```
_.map( array2, function( value ){ return value.toUpperCase() } )
```

Comment: why would anyone replace totally native functionally with a huge library

Comment: @LukeRobertson If you have access to `.map` natively, go for it. At the time of writing, the `.map` function was not a native method without ES6.

Answer (score 0):

**Easily you can convert into `uppercase` or `lowercase` .**

```js
var my_array = ["melon","banana","apple","orange","lemon"];

function convertToUppercase() {
  var e = document.getElementById('show');
  e.innerHTML = "Uppercase: " + String(my_array).toUpperCase().split(",");
  console.log(String(my_array).toUpperCase().split(","));
}

function convertToLowercase() {
  console.clear();
  var e = document.getElementById('show');
  e.innerHTML = "Lowercase: " +  String(my_array).toLowerCase().split(",");
  console.log(String(my_array).toLowerCase().split(","));
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #0095ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #999;
   box-shadow: 0 0 8px #999;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="convertToUppercase()">Convert to Uppercase</button>
<button onclick="convertToLowercase()">Convert to Lowercase</button>
<p id="show"></p>
```

Comment: fail in case, `my_array = ["me,lon","banana","apple","orange","lemon"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var array2 = ["melon","banana","apple","orange","lemon"];

array2.map(fruit => fruit.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the values of an array. To do so, you have to iterate through the array first before applying your desired method on the array. That way, each value will take the applied method.

```
const array2 = ["melon","banana","apple","orange","lemon"];

/*create another variable (newArr) which would store your "loop through array2"*/

const newArr = array2.map(arr => arr.toUpperCase());

console.log(newArr);
```

QED

Answer (score 0):

***To recap :***

There are 2 main methods to do it :

**1. Using the modern Javascript ES6 version with arrow function and map() iterator :**

```
// the test array

const items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'];

// declare the function with arrow function using the map iterator and the 
// toUpperCase() buildin method

const countItems = arr => arr.map(item => item.toUpperCase());
```

**2. Using the old good function style with a simple for loop, the toUpperCase() buildin method and the push() method**

```
// the test array

const items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'];

// the old way

function countItems(arr) {
  newarray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
    newarray.push(arr[i].toUpperCase());
  }
  return newarray;
};
```

**3. call the function with any of the above snippets**

```
console.log(countItems(items));
```

// Should print

**[ 'ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3', 'ITEM4', 'ITEM5', 'ITEM6' ]**

> hope that this answer adds a small stone to whatever you want to build

Answer (score -2):

```
var name = ['Amit','Sumit','Kumit'];
var newname = name.join('-').toUpperCase().split();
console.log(newname);
```

Comment: fail in case, `var name = ['Am-it','Sumit','Kumit'];`