# How to convert array content to uppercase?

Tags: javascript

Is there a non backwards way to turn exactly one array index into an uppercase string?
I don't want to split, loop or anything else, because I only need this one string.

```
colors = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
red = colors[0];
redUpper = red.toUppercase();
```

This won't work, because `toUppercase()` is a string function. I know that. I'm only looking for the simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: `toUppercase()` isn't a javascript function at all. It's `toUpperCase()`

Comment: i second @baao comment. and your snippet should works if you use correct function `toUpperCase()`

Comment: I think this question is duplicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719329/convert-array-into-upper-case

Answer (score 10):

If you only want the first element upper case, you can use the `String#toUpperCase` function:

```js
const colors = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
const redUpper = colors[0].toUpperCase();
console.log(redUpper);
```

If you want them all, use `Array#Map`.

```js
const colors = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
console.log(colors.map(a => a.toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: _I don't want to split, loop or anything else, because I only need this one string._

Comment: @baao Sorry I was answering the question in the title :) answer updated

Comment: This covered both the scenario's which OP asked for. Still the downvotes when helping ? hmm.

Comment: I removed mine @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using

```js
const colors = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
console.log(colors.map(function(x){
    return x.toUpperCase();
}));
```

If you want to change the first element to uppercase then use

```js
const colors = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
colors[0] = colors[0].toUpperCase();
console.log(colors);
```

Comment: _I don't want to split, loop or anything else, because I only need this one string._

Comment: only the first element ?

Comment: edited for handling only first element

Answer (score 2):

you need to assign your value to the array element you want to change

```
var arr = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
arr[0] = arr[0].toUpperCase()
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Mostly this is what OP failing to explain. Good catch

Answer (score 1):

```js
colors = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
console.log(colors[0].toUpperCase())
```

You have a typo error in your code: `toUppercase != toUpperCase`