# JS use push in the for and apply toUpperCase

Tags: javascript

//I need to do this with for

```js
var name = ["Jhon", "Anne", "Ewreck", "Nine"];

for( var i = 0 ; i < name.length ; i++ ){
    name[i].push(name[i].toUpperCase());
    console.log(name[i]);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert array into upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719329/convert-array-into-upper-case)

Comment: Do not use `name` as a variable name in the window.scope `let names = ["Jhon", "Anne", "Ewreck", "Nine"]; names = names.map(name=>name.toUpperCase())`

Comment: Thanks, its worked. But you now if whit for its worked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
let name = ["Jhon", "Anne", "Ewreck", "Nine"];
let nameUpper = name.map( x => x.toUpperCase() )
console.log(nameUpper);
```

Comment: Thanks, its worked. But you now if whit for its worked or not?